# How to use IP received from VPN Server to access internal network

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dns

happy new year.
I am working on the setup of this network as follow:

- An AWS EC2 VPN Server (SoftEther) that has Internet IP address of 175.41.157.xxx that a client can access via the Internet. After the user login into the VPN Server, they will be assign an IP inside the range of: 192.168.10.2 - 192.168.10.253 /24 ; DNS: 172.31.20.10. For example: 192.168.10.2
- The default gateway will be 192.168.10.1; the server has another interface that connects to internal network of 172.31.20.0/24, the interface has an IP of: 172.31.20.5
- Inside the said network of 172.31.20.0/24 is an DNS Server (172.31.20.10) which was built to do the filtering.

The problem is that all queries that hit the DNS Server have been made using the interface IP of 172.31.20.5 (the interface of the VPN Server into the internal network).

Is there anyway that I can config VPN Server to use the client IP of 192.168.10.2 to access the DNS Server of 172.31.20.10 ?

Any VPN Server software can do.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done.

First, it is not clear why you want to.  This sounds like there may be an "XY Problem" situation at hand.  That is, you have something desirable in mind (perhaps to avoid a certain problem) and you have a solution in mind, and are asking about that solution.  However, I suspect there might be an easier way to accomplish the actual goal you have in mind.  For instance, you might wish to alter how your DNS server responds to certain types of requests.  It might be easier to have the DNS server use an address starting with 192.168.10. (in addition to 172.31.20.10), possibly using some sort of "split horizon" settings.

Anyway, onto your question:

You can typically assign a computer's network interface to have multiple IPv4 addresses.  So you can have that "VPN Server" use the address of 192.168.10.2

Depending on how smart your computer is, you might then need to manually adjust the settings of the VPN software service, so it doesn't think of 192.168.10.2 as an address that it might use to hand out to a client.

Then, it does not violate any software protocol to have the VPN software send out a TCP packet that says it comes from 192.168.10.2.

However, the computer which is the VPN server might not be inclined to use 192.168.10.2 as the source address if it plans to send traffic out the network interface with a 172.31.20.5 address on it.  So while the IP protocol and general routing rules should give you no problems on other devices, you'll need to convince the local computer to do that.

How you do that would depend on the software (e.g., including the TCP/IP stack, so depending on which operating system) is running on the VPN Server computer.  This might not be easy (or widely supported), but if the software provides such an option, then this could likely work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, I switched to OpenVPN Server and can get the final result. I believe the problem is the config of SoftEther.